# issue after xcode update PCH file built from different branch

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updated to xcode 4.6.2 and upon running the program I am getting the following error:

```
 PCH file built from a different branch ((clang-425.0.27)) than the compiler ((clang-425.0.28))
```

How do I fix this error and where is it coming from. It has come up from no where I have never seen an error as such before.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Google... Clean the build.

Comment: Clean your build, including folders. Do a search before posting a question, it's much easier :)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027725/xcode-version-4-6-2-4h1003-compiler-error

Comment: Ahem.. Google's top result leads here. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer was simple... I simply had to clean my program as suggested from the comments above